# Convergence of ODE's solution if derivative has 2 isolated zeros

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm going through Mark Levi's [Ordinary Differential Equations, an intuitive introduction](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/417/lib/ODE.pdf) and on page 61, I've encountered the following problem:

> Problem 2.9. Consider the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $a < b$ be two isolated zeros of $f(x)$, with $f(x) > 0$ for all $a < x < b$. Prove that for any solution with $x(0) \in (a, b)$ we have $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = b$, $\lim_{t \to -\infty} x(t) = a$.

I think there's a counterexample to this:

Consider the function $x(t) = -\cos(t + \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a small constant. We can express $t$ in terms of $x$ as follows:

$$
-x = \cos(t + \epsilon) \Rightarrow t = \arccos(-x) - \epsilon
$$

The derivative of $x(t)$ is:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \sin(t + \epsilon) = \sin(\arccos(-x) - \epsilon + \epsilon) = \sin(\arccos(-x)) = f(x)
$$

Let $a=-1$ and $b=1$. We observe that $f(a) = f(-1) = \sin(\arccos(-1)) = 0$ and $f(b) = f(1) = \sin(\arccos(1)) = 0$, and also that $f(x) > 0$ when $x \in (-1, 1)$ (I verified this via [plotting](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zmqfvcbuvx) $f(x)$).

At $t=0$, for small positive $\epsilon$, the value $x(0)$ is a bit above $-1$:

$$
-1 = a \lt x(0) = -\cos(\epsilon) \lt 1 = b
$$

so we have $x(0) \in (a, b)$ as the original problem stated.

I think this definition of $x(t)$, its derivative and $f(x)$ matches up with what the original problem statement requires. However, $x(t)$ does not approach a limit as $t \to \pm\infty$; instead, it oscillates indefinitely. Where's the mistake?

Comment: I haven't browsed your "counterexample", but the question asked can be given an answer by reasoning on stability/unstability : see pictures 3.2 and 3.3 pages 78,79 of this document.

Comment: @Gonçalo I don't see how it would because the present problem does not seem to prohibit oscillatory solutions?

Comment: Since $f(x)>0$ in the interval $(-1,1)$, it can be rewritten as 
$$
f(x)=\sin(\arccos(-x))=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos(-x))}=\sqrt{1-x^2}.
$$
Therefore, your example is the same one discussed in that question. The answer to it explains why the solutions to $\dot{x}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ do not oscillate.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for spelling it out, it's starting to make sense now. So when I'm expressing the derivative in terms of t, then the solution oscillates but when I express it in terms of x, then it doesn't? I thought the two ways are equivalent, but apparently they aren't.